# What amperage should a 5 volt power pack be to safely use with a random 5v device to avoid the risk of burning out the device (i.e. an apple tablet)

Tags: voltage, power, amperage

I have a number of variable power packs one of which supplies the 5volts I need to for a particular device. The output is "500mA MAX". I worry that as happened once before with an ipad I might burn something out but I don't really understand what the amperage is all about (i.e. how do you work out if a specific amperage is OK, and what happens if it's not?)

Comment: It’s a bit like cash. If you have more Amps than required, then you’re ok. If you don’t have enough, that’s bad. Personally I’d avoid using random power supplies on expensive gadgets. You gets what you pays for.

Comment: If apple did't current limit protect their outputs, I'd be surprised